# ASP.NET MVC (CRUD operation) error while removing the data from database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

The data is saved successfully in database but it has problem while removing from database. The connection is failed. The error says

Error source:

> System.Data, Error message: Invalid operation .the connection is closed

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwhKM.png)

the connection is automatically closed and it has to be refresh in database otherwise it displays error message in database, and when I execute the program data is successfully save in database but the problem while removing from database.

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DeleteEvent(int eventID)
    {

        var status = false;
        using (MyEventEntities dc = new MyEventEntities())
        {

            var v = dc.Events.Where(a => a.EventId == eventID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null)
            {
                dc.Events.Remove(v);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
            
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
 $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
          if (selectedEvent != null && confirm('Are You sure?')) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: '/home/DeleteEvent',
                  data: { 'eventID': selectedEvent.eventID },
                 
                  success: function (data) {
                      if (data.status)
                      {
                          FetchCalendar();
                          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                      } 
                  },
                       error: function () {
                      alert('Failed');
                  }
              })
          } 
      })
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information than that. We know nothing about your system.

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and include code, esp. the bits where you open & close database connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is not open.

You can't talk on the telephone when the receiver is hung up. Wait, that's an out of date analogy. OK, you can't send a text when you have zero bars of signal.

The code you've provided does not show the EF context being created; the error is probably there. Perhaps in the `MyEntities` constructor, or something called by that constructor.